# CS50 Recover - Why do I keep getting a segmentation fault?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, cs50, recover

I'm a complete beginner at programming and I really can't understand where I've gone wrong. I've looked at other people's code and changed numerous things but nothing has worked :/ Any help would be appreciated!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage ./recover image\n");
        return 1;
    }

    FILE *card = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    if (card == NULL)
    {
        printf("ERROR\n");
        return 1;
    }

    int jpeg_num = 0;
    typedef uint8_t BYTE;
    BYTE buffer[512];
    char filename[10];
    FILE *image = NULL;

    while (fread(buffer, sizeof(BYTE), 1, card) == 1)
    {
        if (buffer[0] == 0xff && buffer[1] == 0xd0 && buffer[2] == 0xff && (buffer[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0)
        {

            if (jpeg_num > 0)
            {
                fclose(image);
            }

            sprintf(filename, "%03i.jpeg", jpeg_num);
            image = fopen(filename, "w");
            fwrite(buffer, sizeof(BYTE), 1, image);
            jpeg_num++;
        }

        else
        {
            fwrite(buffer, sizeof(BYTE), 1, image);
        }
    }

    fclose(image);
    fclose(card);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you run your code through a debugger it should stop you on the exact line where the segfault occured (which may not be the same line where your bug is, but if you inspect the values of certain variables at that point you should be able to figure it out from context.)

Comment: `fread(buffer, sizeof(BYTE), 1, card)` is reading only **one byte** but you are examining other bytes in the buffer. Always capture the return value from `fread` so you know how much to write.

Comment: `fwrite(buffer, sizeof(BYTE), 1, image);` in the else clause can/will fire against a `NULL` image file pointer in this code. If the if-clause is not met at least once, `image` will be null, and that code invokes undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

CS50 causes programs to be compiled using an address sanitizer (`-fsanitize=address`), right? If so, you should have received something like the following:

```
ASAN:DEADLYSIGNAL
=================================================================
==4179==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: SEGV on unknown address 0x000000000000 (pc 0x7f280eabf92e bp 0x000000000001 sp 0x7fffc6e02bd0 T0)
==4179==The signal is caused by a READ memory access.
==4179==Hint: address points to the zero page.
    #0 0x7f280eabf92d in _IO_fwrite (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x7f92d)
    #1 0x7f281020107f in main /.../a.c:45
    #2 0x7f280ea61b96 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x21b96)
    #3 0x7f2810200c79 in _start (/.../a+0xc79)

AddressSanitizer can not provide additional info.
SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: SEGV (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x7f92d) in _IO_fwrite
==4179==ABORTING
```

(This is from `gcc` rather than `clang`, but `clang`'s address sanitizer should give something similar.)

So you attempted to read from address zero. This could be `NULL` or an initialized pointer. We even known it happened in the call to `fwrite` at line 45!

There are two pointers being passed to `fwrite`, `buffer` and `image`. `buffer` is an automatically allocated array, so it's a valid pointer. `image`, on the other hand, is initialized as follows:

```c
FILE *image = NULL;
```

Is it possible that it's never changed before reaching the failing call to `fwrite`? Yes. That's bad.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I understand where the problem lies but where/how do I change it before fwrite? Sorry, I just can't figure out what I need to add :/